# Toolbar falls down after select text

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have an toolbar, main theme: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`
In API 19 ,after i select text inside TextView, inside SimpleTableAdapert, my tool bar  falls down, and i see "Text selection" menu. After i remove my finger from TextView, menu is gone, so i cant copy text.
In API 24 its ok.
How to solve it?
[image]

Comment: Check this http://www.androhub.com/android-contextual-action-mode-over-toolbar/

Comment: Your image creating wrong question understanding... seems like you want that menu.. but you are asking about fallen toolbar.. so just circle on toolbar not that menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `windowActionModeOverlay` to `true` in your style theme

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```